# React.useContext is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am just starting with the useContext hook in React, but cannot get it to work.
In the file App.js, I define the value in the App component:

```
  const StateValue = React.createContext(null);
```

Then, I try to pass a function from useState with the following code in the return segment of the same component:

```
 <StateValue.Provider value={setLogState}>
          {logState === 1 ? (
            <Register setLogState={setLogState} register={register} />
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
          {logState === 2 ? (
            <Login setLogState={setLogState} login={login} />
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
          {logState === 3 ? (
            <List
              color={color}
              historicData={historicData}
              history={history}
              tickersData={tickersData}
              addTicker={addTicker}
              deleteTicker={deleteTicker}
              tickers={tickers}
            />
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </StateValue.Provider>
```

In a separate file, called list.js, I get the context using

```
  let data = React.useContext(StateValue);
```

but receive an error

```
src\Components\list.js
  Line 8:31:  'StateValue' is not defined  no-undef
```

I am referecing this guide: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

It seems that the passed value should be an object, but I want to pass a function. Do I need to import it? How do I fix the above error?

Comment: You are probably not exporting and/or importing correctly.

Comment: I guess you didnt export/import it, you should show a complete code, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How do I import/export useContext, can you give me a link/reference

Comment: Sorry that I didn't post the whole code, I know it is a good practice when asking a question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is export your `stateValue` in your `App.js` file

```
export const StateValue = React.createContext(null);
```

There after you need to import it in your `List.js` file

```
import { StateValue } from "../../App.js";
```

Comment: I moved the code over the App component and added the export, but the error persists. Do I have to import it?